# Django Weasyprint on Elastic Beanstalk - Could not load GDK-Pixbuf

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, weasyprint

I've installed weasyprint on Elastic Beanstalk. The printing of html templates is working so far but im not able to print svg images.

Weasyprint throws the following error:

```
Failed to load image at "https://myurl/media/X247QAQ2IO.svg" (Could not load GDK-Pixbuf. PNG and SVG are the only image formats available.)
```

Do I need gdk-pixbuf to print SVGs? And if so how can I install it on Amazon Linux?

```
Yum does not have gdk-pixbuf2 available for installation
```

Comment: Heads up - the library is actually called `gdkpixbuf-2.0` so `yum install gdkpixbuf-2.0` would work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me by manually building gdk-pixbuf2, My script below derived from https://gist.github.com/whyvez/1e0212a35da97aa8f1b1  where they needed to install image magic

weazy.conf

```
files:
 "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/00_instal_weasyprint_prerequisites.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash

      yum install -y libxml2-devel libxslt-devel python-devel redhat-rpm-config libffi-devel cairo pango

      export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
      export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
      export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
      export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
      export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include

      sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
      sudo yum update -y
      sudo yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ glib2-devel.x86_64 libxml2-devel.x86_64 libpng-devel.x86_64 \
      libjpeg-turbo-devel.x86_64 gobject-introspection.x86_64 gobject-introspection-devel.x86_64

      wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/libcroco/0.6/libcroco-0.6.8.tar.xz
      tar xvfJ libcroco-0.6.8.tar.xz
      cd libcroco-0.6.8
      ./configure --prefix=/usr
      make
      sudo make install
      cd ..

      wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gdk-pixbuf/2.28/gdk-pixbuf-2.28.2.tar.xz
      tar xvfJ gdk-pixbuf-2.28.2.tar.xz
      cd gdk-pixbuf-2.28.2
      ./configure --prefix=/usr --without-libtiff
      make
      sudo make install
      cd ..

      sudo yum install -y pixman-devel.x86_64 harfbuzz-devel.x86_64 freetype-devel.x86_64

      wget wget http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/release/fontconfig-2.10.91.tar.gz
      tar xvf fontconfig-2.10.91.tar.gz
      cd fontconfig-2.10.91
      ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-libxml2
      make
      sudo make install
      cd ..

      wget http://cairographics.org/releases/cairo-1.12.14.tar.xz
      tar xvfJ cairo-1.12.14.tar.xz
      cd cairo-1.12.14
      ./configure --prefix=/usr
      make
      sudo make install
      cd ..

      wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pango/1.34/pango-1.34.1.tar.xz
      tar xvfJ pango-1.34.1.tar.xz
      cd pango-1.34.1
      ./configure --prefix=/usr
      make
      sudo make install
      cd ..

      wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/librsvg/2.40/librsvg-2.40.6.tar.xz
      tar xvfJ librsvg-2.40.6.tar.xz
      cd librsvg-2.40.6
      ./configure --prefix=/usr
      make
      sudo make install
      cd ..


      sudo ldconfig /usr/lib
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks! I simplified it because I only needed gdk-pixbuf since I wasn't able to have JPEGs show up in my generated files, and things are working perfectly now.

Comment: Could you help me in what do I do with your script? More specifically I need to have gdkPixbuf in a lambda function

Comment: Not sure on lambda. You would have to read up on how to build dependencies on deployment packages

Comment: I know this is a little out of date, but I'm hoping someone can help.  When I apply this the images come up which is great.  But the href links stop working, which isn't.  I've tried upgrading the various packages to latest versions but the implementation fails with `OSError: cannot load library 'libpangocairo-1.0.so.0': /lib64/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: FcWeightFromOpenTypeDouble`

Answer (score 2):

After further investigation I realised that this error should not occur at all using svg images. This is the relevant part of the weasyprint source code:

```
    if mime_type == 'image/svg+xml':
        # No fallback for XML-based mimetypes as defined by MIME
        # Sniffing Standard, see https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/
        image = SVGImage(string, url)
    else:
        # Try to rely on given mimetype
        try:
            if mime_type == 'image/png':
                try:
                    surface = cairocffi.ImageSurface.create_from_png(
                            BytesIO(string))
                except Exception as exception:
                        raise ImageLoadingError.from_exception(exception)
                else:
                    image = RasterImage(surface)
            else:
                image = None
        except ImageLoadingError:
            image = None

        # Relying on mimetype didn't work, give the image to GDK-Pixbuf
        if not image:
            if pixbuf is None:
                raise ImageLoadingError(
                        'Could not load GDK-Pixbuf. PNG and SVG are '
                        'the only image formats available.')
```

As you can see, if it's a png or svg with the right mime-type pixbuf isn't used at all. After reading this I realized that it has to be an issue with the svg it's self.
The image server, S3 in my case served the svg with the wrong content_type.

After fixing this the error didn't occure anymore and I can print SVGs with weasyprint.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this problem as well. Unless you absolutely need the latest version of `WeasyPrint` you can set it to a version that doesn't require `gdk-pixbuf2` in requirements.txt.

```
WeasyPrint==0.26
```

(It might work with a later verison than 0.26, it is just what I had in one of my projects)

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, for a long time..fixed by installing weazyprint==52.5, and uninstall django-weazyprint

```
pip install WeasyPrint==52.5
```

created a config file in as mentioned in this thread: https://gist.github.com/Abdoulrasheed/039b1f4afd4268a8832d8066881d7b23

finally worked