# installing gdk-pixbuf on Elastic Beanstalk v2

Tags: django, linux, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get Django-Weasyprint working correctly on an AWS Linux2 Elastic Beanstalk instance.  I have come across [this question][1] and when I add the code to `.platform/hooks/predeploy` the images all work but the href links stop working.

I have, therefore, tried to upgrade the packages within the script and my script now looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

yum install -y libxml2-devel libxslt-devel python-devel redhat-rpm-config libffi-devel cairo pango

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include

sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ glib2-devel.x86_64 libxml2-devel.x86_64 libpng-devel.x86_64 \
libjpeg-turbo-devel.x86_64 gobject-introspection.x86_64 gobject-introspection-devel.x86_64

wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/libcroco/0.6/libcroco-0.6.13.tar.xz
tar xvfJ libcroco-0.6.13.tar.xz
cd libcroco-0.6.13
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
cd ..

wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gdk-pixbuf/2.42/gdk-pixbuf-2.42.6.tar.xz
tar xvfJ gdk-pixbuf-2.42.6.tar.xz
cd gdk-pixbuf-2.42.6
./configure --prefix=/usr --without-libtiff
make
sudo make install
cd ..

sudo yum install -y pixman-devel.x86_64 harfbuzz-devel.x86_64 freetype-devel.x86_64

wget http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/release/fontconfig-2.13.93.tar.gz
tar xvf fontconfig-2.13.93.tar.gz
cd fontconfig-2.13.93
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-libxml2
make
sudo make install
cd ..

wget http://cairographics.org/releases/cairo-1.16.0.tar.xz
tar xvfJ cairo-1.16.0.tar.xz
cd cairo-1.16.0
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
cd ..

wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pango/1.48/pango-1.48.4.tar.xz
tar xvfJ pango-1.48.4.tar.xz
cd pango-1.48.4
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
cd ..

wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/librsvg/2.50/librsvg-2.50.5.tar.xz
tar xvfJ librsvg-2.50.5.tar.xz
cd librsvg-2.50.5
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
cd ..


sudo ldconfig /usr/lib
```

It generates the following error:

> OSError: cannot load library 'libpangocairo-1.0.so.0':
> /lib64/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol:
> FcWeightFromOpenTypeDouble

I don't know how to resolve and would appreciate some help - thanks
[1]: [Django Weasyprint on Elastic Beanstalk - Could not load GDK-Pixbuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820538/django-weasyprint-on-elastic-beanstalk-could-not-load-gdk-pixbuf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was to put the following `01_weasyprint.sh` file in `hooks > predeploy > 01_weasyprint.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

yum install -y libxml2-devel libxslt-devel python-devel redhat-rpm-config libffi-devel cairo pango

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include

sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ glib2-devel.x86_64 libxml2-devel.x86_64 libpng-devel.x86_64 \
libjpeg-turbo-devel.x86_64 gobject-introspection.x86_64 gobject-introspection-devel.x86_64

wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/libcroco/0.6/libcroco-0.6.8.tar.xz
tar xvfJ libcroco-0.6.8.tar.xz
cd libcroco-0.6.8
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
cd ..

wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gdk-pixbuf/2.28/gdk-pixbuf-2.28.2.tar.xz
tar xvfJ gdk-pixbuf-2.28.2.tar.xz
cd gdk-pixbuf-2.28.2
./configure --prefix=/usr --without-libtiff
make
sudo make install
cd ..

sudo yum install -y pixman-devel.x86_64 harfbuzz-devel.x86_64 freetype-devel.x86_64

wget http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/release/fontconfig-2.13.93.tar.gz
tar xvf fontconfig-2.13.93.tar.gz
cd fontconfig-2.13.93
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-libxml2
make
sudo make install
cd ..

wget http://cairographics.org/releases/cairo-1.16.0.tar.xz
tar xvfJ cairo-1.16.0.tar.xz
cd cairo-1.16.0
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
cd ..

wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pango/1.48/pango-1.48.4.tar.xz
tar xvfJ pango-1.48.4.tar.xz
cd pango-1.48.4
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
cd ..

wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/librsvg/2.40/librsvg-2.40.6.tar.xz
tar xvfJ librsvg-2.40.6.tar.xz
cd librsvg-2.40.6
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
cd ..


sudo ldconfig /usr/lib
```